# Calling autorelease in a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, autorelease, nsautoreleasepool

There’s a memory management issue with the following code:

```
dispatch_after(someTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [objectA doSomething];
                [self doSomethingDifferent];
            });


//self’s dealloc:

- (void)dealloc
{
   _objectA.delgate = nil; //objectA’s delegate is this object;
   [super dealloc]
}
```

“self” has a reference to objectA but is not retaining objectA.  In self’s dealloc it touches objectA.  This is a problem if objectA has already been dealloced.  I know that by referencing these objects in the block, they will be retained, but I’m not sure there’s anyway to determine in what order they will be released.

One thing that seems to work is this:

```
dispatch_after(someTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [[objectA retain] autorelease];
                [objectA doSomething];
                [self doSomethingDifferent];
            });
```

It seems that the autorelease pool is then drained after the block releases the objects but I’m not sure that that’s a guarantee so I don’t know if this code is valid.

Comment: You're showing bits of code that doesn't let us see what's going on. For example, is `objectA` a local variable? instance variable? global variable? is it different from `_objectA`?

Answer (score 0):

The class in which that `-dealloc` method is implemented should hold a **zeroing weak** reference to `_objectA`. In that case, you don't have to worry about it. If the object referenced by `_objectA` was deallocated first, then `_objectA` will be `nil` when you access it, which is safe.